# How can I open Android app using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, oracle-apex

I have an application developed with Oracle APEX 22.2. My page has 2 number items that have longitude and latitude values, and a button that executes JavaScript code. When the button is clicked, it should open Google Maps app on users Android phones and pass the items values to Google Maps app and execute the "start driving" functionality of the Maps app.
I am Ok if it will ask for the user's permission to run the app first.
Can this or any part of it be done using JavaScript?

Comment: No.  The browser lives in a sandbox.  You can't have any impact on local applications.  You shouldn't be assuming you're on a particular type of device anyway.  Can't you do this with maps.google.com?

Comment: maps.google.com does not have the "Start Driving" functionality.